# Непонятная ошибка Ursina Engine

Tags: python, ursina

У меня есть проблема в коде на Python на движке Ursina. Как мне кажется, в моём коде нет ошибок, а ошибки в файлах Python или в чём-то ещё. Вот текст ошибки:

```
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Python project\Ballrollgame.py", line 75, in <module>
    color_picker = ButtonGroup(('Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow'), selected='Red', horizontal=True, parent=color_menu)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ursina\prefabs\button_group.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.select(self.buttons[i])
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\ursina\prefabs\button_group.py", line 77, in select
    if b in self.selected and self.min_selection > 0 and len(self.selected) >= self.min_selection:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not Button.
```

Вот весь код игры:

```
from ursina import *
import random


def update():
    global score

    # Движение шарика
    ball.x += held_keys['d'] * time.dt * 3
    ball.x -= held_keys['a'] * time.dt * 3

    # Отслеживание столкновения шарика и подарков
    for gift in gifts:
        if ball.intersects(gift):
            destroy(gift)
            score += 10

    # Отслеживание столкновения шарика и мусорных вёдер
    for bin in bins:
        if ball.intersects(bin):
            score -= 10

    # Повышение уровня, если достигнута нужная сумма очков
    if score >= level_threshold:
        increase_level()


def create_gift():
    gift = Entity(model='sphere', color=color.red, scale=0.2)
    gift.x = random.uniform(-3, 3)
    gift.y = 3
    gifts.append(gift)


def create_bin():
    bin = Entity(model='cube', color=color.green, scale=0.3)
    bin.x = random.uniform(-3, 3)
    bin.y = 3
    bins.append(bin)


def increase_level():
    global level_threshold

    level_threshold += 20

    # Увеличить скорость движения подарков и мусорных вёдер
    for gift in gifts:
        gift.y_speed += 1
    for bin in bins:
        bin.y_speed += 1


app = Ursina()

camera.orthographic = True
camera.fov = 20

ball = Entity(model='sphere', color=color.orange, scale=0.3, collider='sphere')
ball.gravity = 0
ball.x = 0
ball.y = -3

gifts = []
bins = []

score = 0
level = 1
level_threshold = 20

Text(text=f'Score: {score}', position=(-0.8, 0.45))

color_menu = Entity(layout='grid', parent=scene, position=(0.8, 0.45))
Text(parent=color_menu, text='Color', color=color.black)
color_picker = ButtonGroup(('Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow'), selected='Red', horizontal=True, parent=color_menu)

background_color_menu = Entity(layout='grid', parent=scene, position=(0.8, 0.25))
Text(parent=background_color_menu, text='Background Color', color=color.black)
background_color_picker = ButtonGroup(('White', 'Black', 'Gray', 'Custom'), selected='White', horizontal=True,
                                      parent=background_color_menu)

game_over_text = Text(text='', color=color.red, position=(0, 0), origin=(0.5, 0))

app.run()
```